# How to store user data in a session?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I would like to populate my $_SESSION array with all DB data of the relevant user that just logged in.

like "FIRST_NAME" in the DB would be $_SESSION["FIRST_NAME"];

What is the way to do that properly ?

```
 $_SESSION = $result_set; //$result_set is the fetched array from the DB
```

Yielded an error (unknown() at line 0)

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to populate my $_SESSION array with all DB data of the relevant user that just logged in.

Don't do this. Store only the row ID in the session, and do a database request any time you need some information.

Storing this information in the session is completely redundant, and may lead to outdated data if the user changes something in the database that isn't reflected in the session variable.

Comment: ok, was actually thinking of saving my server some extra db accesses

Comment: @Ted yeah. It's not worth it in this case, if the database is indexed properly and all, it won't be much of a burden.

Comment: Forgot to mention this is a page where the user is all about updating personal data...

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a name for the data you're storing - you can't overwrite the $_SESSION variable completely.

EG:

```
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_set->id;
```

Just as Pekka said, there's rarely the need to store the entire user profile in the session when you can do a separate database call to gather this data later.